# Using Python How to log in into a protected website

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to login into this website using selenium and requests in python. Unfortunately I could not able to login. could you please help. Please check the python code.

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
 from selenium import webdriver
 from fake_useragent import UserAgent
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

 headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36'}

 driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')

 page2 = 'https://data.world/makeovermonday/2019w16'

 driver.get(page2)

 u = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('username')
 u.send_keys('********') # username
 p = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('Password')
 p.send_keys('*********') # password
 p.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

 inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("fileactions.files.download")
 inputElement.click()
 ##inputElement.find_elements("UnifiedExport__miLink___EXLKS").click()
 ##inputElement.send_keys(company)
 ##driver.find_elements_by_link_text("UnifiedExport__miLink___EXLKS")
```

Comment: Any exceptions? What exactly do you mean by "I could not able to login"?

Comment: I don't see login form anywhere (not without clicking on sign in anyway). And there are no elements with `username` or `Password` tags. You should also explain what *exactly* is the problem.

Comment: If you go to this websiete  "https://data.world/makeovermonday/2019w16 " top right corner there is a signin option. my question is how can i signin using python? I try in my own way but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the co-founders of data.world (the site in question above) - just so you know - we have a full API and even a Python SDK that will either pull down files, execute queries and even get dataframes from data hosted on data.world.  See https://docs.data.world/ and also check out our open Slack community for questions like this. I wouldn't recommend trying to scrape our site as a workflow... it's technically against our terms of service and will likely be a pretty brittle way to interact with our site.  The API/SDKs will be so much easier for what it looks like you're trying to do!  If the API/SDKs won't work for your use case, I'd love to hear more!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I got instruction from this link: https://github.com/datadotworld/data.world-py I installed the library also i configure dw configure in the command Prompt then I copied token from data.world under advanced option. But when i run the code which i copied from the above link i got this message **RestApiError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://download.data.world/datapackage/jonloyens/an-intro-to-dataworld-dataset**

Comment: Hey man - thanks for trying that out - I'm having our support team look into - in the interim would you mind filing a support ticket for this so we can track your issues and move them into an official channel?  (you can file a support ticket by hitting the ? button on the lower right of any page in data.world)

Answer (score 2):

Use `WebDriverWait` and follwoing code should work.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome("path of chrome driver")

driver.get("https://data.world/makeovermonday/2019w16")
element=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a.btn.btn-sm.navbar-btn span')))
element.click()

userelement=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[placeholder="Username or email address"]')))

userelement.send_keys("abcd@gmail.com")

passelement=WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[placeholder="Password"]')))

passelement.send_keys("44555565")

passelement.submit()
```

[image]